# How to write bitmaps as frames to H.264 with x264 in C\C++?

Tags: c++, c, frames, h.264

How to write bitmaps (RGB) as frames to H.264 with x264 in C\C++?

Some Examples with source would be great!

Comment: Almost identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736304/how-to-write-bitmaps-as-frames-to-ogg-theora-in-c-c  Depending on your OS, it may be possible to very easily encode to either codec with very similar code, so perhaps open just one question for now and ask how to programattically encode video in multiple codecs, including both h264 and theora?