# How to write bitmaps as frames to Ogg Theora in C\C++?

Tags: c++, c, ogg-theora

How to write bitmaps as frames to Ogg Theora in C\C++?

Some Examples with source would be grate!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the [libtheora API](http://www.theora.org/doc/libtheora-1.1/) and [example code](http://svn.xiph.org/trunk/theora/examples/).

Here's a [micro howto](http://people.xiph.org/~j/ogg-theora-microhowto.html) that shows how to use the theora binaries. As the encoder reads *raw, uncompressed 'yuv4mpeg' data for video* you could use that from your app, too by piping the video frames to the encoder.

Answer (score 9):

The entire solution is a little lengthy to post on here as a code sample, but if you download libtheora from Xiph.org, there is an example png2theora. All of the library functions I am about to mention can be found in the documentation on Xiph.org for theora and ogg.

1. Call th_info_init() to initialise a th_info structure, then set up you output parameters by assigning the appropriate members in that.
2. Use that structure in a call to th_encode_alloc() to get an encoder context
3. Initialise an ogg stream, with ogg_stream_init()
4. Initialise a blank th_comment structure using th_comment_init

Iterate through the following:

5. Call th_encode_flushheader with the the encoder context, the blank comment structure and an ogg_packet.
6. Send the resulting packet to the ogg stream with ogg_stream_packetin()

Until th_encode_flushheader returns 0 (or an error code)

Now, repeatedly call ogg_stream_pageout(), every time writing the page.header and then page.body to an output file, until it returns 0. Now call ogg_stream_flush and write the resulting page to the file.

You can now write frames to the encoder. Here is how I did it:

```
int theora_write_frame(int outputFd, unsigned long w, unsigned long h, unsigned char *yuv_y, unsigned char *yuv_u, unsigned char *yuv_v, int last)
{
  th_ycbcr_buffer ycbcr;
  ogg_packet op;
  ogg_page og;

  unsigned long yuv_w;
  unsigned long yuv_h;

  /* Must hold: yuv_w >= w */
  yuv_w = (w + 15) & ~15;
  /* Must hold: yuv_h >= h */
  yuv_h = (h + 15) & ~15;

  //Fill out the ycbcr buffer
  ycbcr[0].width = yuv_w;
  ycbcr[0].height = yuv_h;
  ycbcr[0].stride = yuv_w;
  ycbcr[1].width = yuv_w;
  ycbcr[1].stride = ycbcr[1].width;
  ycbcr[1].height = yuv_h;
  ycbcr[2].width = ycbcr[1].width;
  ycbcr[2].stride = ycbcr[1].stride;
  ycbcr[2].height = ycbcr[1].height;

  if(encoderInfo->pixel_fmt == TH_PF_420)
  {
    //Chroma is decimated by 2 in both directions
    ycbcr[1].width = yuv_w >> 1;
    ycbcr[2].width = yuv_w >> 1;
    ycbcr[1].height = yuv_h >> 1;
    ycbcr[2].height = yuv_h >> 1;
  }else if(encoderInfo->pixel_fmt == TH_PF_422)
  {
    ycbcr[1].width = yuv_w >> 1;
    ycbcr[2].width = yuv_w >> 1;
  }else if(encoderInfo->pixel_fmt != TH_PF_422)
  {
    //Then we have an unknown pixel format
    //We don't know how long the arrays are!
    fprintf(stderr, "[theora_write_frame] Unknown pixel format in writeFrame!\n");
    return -1;
  }

  ycbcr[0].data = yuv_y;
  ycbcr[1].data = yuv_u;
  ycbcr[2].data = yuv_v;

  /* Theora is a one-frame-in,one-frame-out system; submit a frame
     for compression and pull out the packet */
  if(th_encode_ycbcr_in(encoderContext, ycbcr)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[theora_write_frame] Error: could not encode frame\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if(!th_encode_packetout(encoderContext, last, &op)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[theora_write_frame] Error: could not read packets\n");
    return -1;
  }

  ogg_stream_packetin(&theoraStreamState, &op);
  ssize_t bytesWritten = 0;
  int pagesOut = 0;
  while(ogg_stream_pageout(&theoraStreamState, &og)) {
    pagesOut ++;
    bytesWritten = write(outputFd, og.header, og.header_len);
    if(bytesWritten != og.header_len)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "[theora_write_frame] Error: Could not write to file\n");
      return -1;
    }
    bytesWritten = write(outputFd, og.body, og.body_len);
    if(bytesWritten != og.body_len)
    {
      bytesWritten = fprintf(stderr, "[theora_write_frame] Error: Could not write to file\n");
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return pagesOut;
}
```

Where encoderInfo is the th_info structure used to initialise the encoder (static in the data section for me).

On your last frame, setting the last frame on th_encode_packetout() will make sure the stream terminates properly.

Once your done, just make sure to clean up (closing fds mainly). th_info_clear() will clear the th_info structure, and th_encode_free() will free your encoder context.

Obviously, you'll need to convert your bitmap into YUV planes before you can pass them to theora_write_frame().

Hope this is of some help. Good luck!